# Advanced logging for Java Web Applications

Tags: java, google-app-engine, logging, jetty, google-cloud-logging

I want to build a more advanced logging mechanism for my java web applications, similar to App engine logs.
My needs are:

1. Stream logs to a database (for ex. sql, bigquery or something else)
2. Automatically log important data (like app context, request url, request id,  browser user agent, user id, etc.)

For point 1, I ca use a "buffering" implementation, where logs are put into different lists, and periodically a cron (thread) gathers all the logs in memory and write's them to database (which can also be on another server)

For point 2, the only way I found of doing this is to inject needed objects into my classes (subsystems), like ServletContext, HttpServletReqest, current user, etc, all modeled into a custom class (let's say AppLogContext), which then can be used by the logging mechanism.

The problem here is that I don't know if this is a good practice. For example, that means that many classes will have to contain this object which has access to servlet context and http request objects and I'm thinking this may create architectural problems (when building modules, layers etc) or even security issues.

App Engine will automatically log this kind of information (and much more, like latencies, cpu usage etc, but this more complicated), and it can be found in the project's Console logs (also it can duplicate logs to big query tables) and I need something for Jetty or other java web app servers.

So, is there another way of doing this, other patterns, different approaches? (couldn't find 3rd party libraries for any of these points)

Thank you.

Comment: Well to give you a piece to the puzzle you seem to be missing: App Engine logs requests. You could achieve this by adding filters. You could make a filter provide a logger instance which is only used for the current request and then handle the write upon request completion. Is this bad practice? Yes, because you add lots of overhead to every request. I recommend you check out the ususal logger frameworks (log4j, etc.) and see what's possible before attempting your own logger which won't be as mature.

Comment: Regarding using the filters, I'm not sure I fully understand, but doesn't this mean that i still have to create a Log object and pass it to all subsystems? So in a custom MyClass, i still would'n be able to call something like Log.getLog().print(myMessage) right?

Comment: I would somehow need a Logger object, with a static method for creation, but with a per request scope... otherwise, without passing a requst (context) data to the used classes, what way of matching (binding) logs messages to request ids would I have? This is very useful when tracking a lot of steps, complex operations, done in a single request, and I could't find a way to achieve smth similar, with logging libraries. Maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: since each request should be handled on a separate thread all logs written during the same request would have the same thread id.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to invent a bicycle.

There is a common practice that you can follow:

- Just log using standard logger to a file
- (*if you need to see logs in request context*) Logback, Log4J and SLF4J supports [Mapped Diagnostic Context (MDC)](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html), that's what you can use to put current request into every log line (just initialize context in a filter, put request id for example, or generate a random uuid). You can aggregate log entries by this id later
- Then use ELK:

  - [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash) got gather logs into
  - ElasticSearch for storing logs
  - to analyze using [Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana)